# Entity framework creating a new entry in referenced table instead of using the existing entry

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF code first approach and i have three types

```
public class A
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public C C {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public C C {get; set;}
}
public class C
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

When I create an entry in B a new row in C is created as expected. I want to refer to the same row created by B in A. Something like below

```
  A a = new A();
  a.C = GetC(id);
  dbContext.A.Add(a);

 public C GetC(int id)
 {
     return dbContext.C.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
 }
```

When i do the above a new entry in C is created. How can I avoid the new entry I want to use the same old entry created by B?

I have tried doing the following but it results in failure citing *another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.*

```
  A a = new A();
  a.C = dbContext.C.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
  dbContext.A.Add(a);
```

Comment: You have two different context instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in ef, then there should be foreign keys (as in the database), and if you add the foreign key to a, this should be enough for make relationships.

But it is in your example that you can use the following:

```
  A a = new A();
  a.C = dbContext.C.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
  dbContext.A.Add(a);
```

After **AsNoTracking** - dbcontect will not cache and track it.
You can read more about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0